# FB.Connect: Callback function for only extends permission dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have to check if a user has permission to "publish_stream.
I tried to run a new
  
but I can not catch the actual login occurred.

If I use
FB.Event.subscribe ('auth.login', function () {
  this is not activated and therefore the function is not performed.

In summary:
User A is logged in but do not have permission to "publish_stream"
- If I login again (with extended permissions) can not have your callback function!

- So how can I check if the user has actually allowed permits "publish_stream"?

i need to use Javascript SDK, not PHP

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bit of a duplicate question, which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084644/fb-connect-callback-function-for-only-extends-permission-dialog), basically, you can make a call to the FB.Data database.  To read up on how to use the FB.Data part of the SDK, it is available at Facebook [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Data.query/) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Data.waitOn/).  Even though it doesn't discuss the permissions part of the database, it should provide some ideas. You may have to edit it a bit for the new oauth schema, but maybe not.  I'll let you know.  ;-)